# Redirect after login to a view

Tags: vaadin

I have implemented a Vaadin (23) app using Spring Boot (2.6). To access the app, users need to be logged in. To manage the login flow, I use the LoginForm of Vaadin. How can I redirect authenticated users to a defined view after login?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to download starter app via https://start.vaadin.com/ select few views to app with different access levels etc. This application will use `VaadinWebSecurity` / `VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that extends the regular Spring Security conf. It will use request cache to store original request and use stored path after login to redirect to view (the mechanism is built-in this helper class and you do not need to implement yourself). See also the documentation:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I would like to override the default redirection process after a successful login. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this done by adding it to the WebSecurity (defaultSuccessUrl):

```
http.formLogin()
                .loginPage((LOGIN_URL)).permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_URL)
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .failureUrl(LOGIN_ERROR);
```

After login the user gets redirect to the Page /dashboard